# JavaScript Link Element over Image

Tags: javascript, window, element

I am trying to intercept all `a` link clicks to do some extra work and this works fine for standalone a links but when it contains an `img` for example the `img` tag is returned instead.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7k28px8/)**

Is there a way to check if the element above is also an `a` link or is there a different way I should be handling this?

**JS :**

```
  document.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e ||  window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if (element.tagName == 'A') {
      window.open(element.href, "_system");
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried event.currentTarget?

Comment: Please try to make a fiddle for your case, since your code should filter just `a` tags.

Comment: Added jsfiddle to explain what is happening.

Comment: You could use element.parentNode and check it's tagName

Answer (score 1):

you can traverse up the parent of the clicked node to see if an ancestor is an `A` tag

```
...
var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
while (element.tagName != 'A' && element.parentNode) {
    element = element.parentNode;
}
if (element.tagName == 'A') {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the handler on the click event of the anchor tags instead of on the whole document, then you will not need to check for the event target.

```
var anchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

var myEventHandler = function() {
    // stuff
};

for (var i = 0; i < anchorTags.length; i++) {
    anchorTags[i].onclick = myEventHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to actually capture all clicks, but if you're looking to capture the anchor tag that was actually clicked, you might consider the approach below.

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0, anchor; anchor = anchors[i]; i++ ) {
 anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e){
      e = e ||  window.event;
      //Grabs the element that initiated the event, the anchor tag.
      var element = this; 
      alert(element.tagName);
      if (element.tagName == 'A') {
          window.open(element.href, "_system");
          return false;
      }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add another condition to check if the current clicked element is a child of `a` element.

You could use **[closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)** method.

> The **`Element.closest()`** method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself) which matches the selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns null.

The condition will be like following :

```
if (element.tagName == 'A' || element.closest('a') != null) {
     window.open(element.closest('a').href, "_system"); //Using the parent a link `href`
     return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
document.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e ||  window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (element.tagName == 'A' || element.closest('a') != null) {
    alert("Open with href :"+element.closest('a').href);
    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p>The below Google text link returns A when clicked, correct!</p>
<a href="google_link">Google Link</a>
<br />
<p>The below Bing image link returns IMG when clicked, incorrect!</p>
<a href="img_link"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></a>
</body>
```